# Staggered Isometric Pathfinder

Tags: algorithm, path, isometric

I have a problem trying to figure out how to implement a path finding system for a staggered isometric map.

I read the A* algorithm and tried to see how it would manifest on an isometric map and the results brought me here.

So the problem lies here (I'm sorry about the cheap display)

[image]

So , I'm currently on the green tile (2,3) and I try to find a path to the red tile (3,1).

Based on A* algorithm I try to calculate the F value of adjacent tiles (I did this only for those 3 tiles).
 As the image displays the F value of (2,1) is lower than (2,2) and this is the mother of all problems , the diagonal tiles with j+2 and j-2 will have (almost) every time a lower F value than the "logical" choice.
 So instead of going to (2,2) it will go to (2,1).

How can I solve this problem? Can somebody give me some hints on what should I do?

Comment: How do you calculate G and H? Oh, and based on the given values, it looks like your H is not [admissible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic). It should take 10 to get from (2,2) to (3,1), but you say it takes 20 (i.e. you overestimate).

Comment: I calculate the distance between (x1,y1) and (x2,y1) like this       H = (Math.Abs(x2-x1) + Math.Abs(y2-y1)) * 10, as for G, I use 10 for direct paths and 14 for diagonals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the given values, it looks like your H is not [admissible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic). Since it takes 10 to get from (2,3) to (2,2), I assume it should take 10 to get from (2,2) to (3,1), but your H says it takes 20 (i.e. you overestimate).

One possible H is the direct distance to the target (either something like [Manhattan distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance) or Euclidean).

At our first step, we explore all neighbours. Our G values will look like: (`G` = green, `R` = red)

```
    14
  10  10
14   R  14
  10  10
G   14
```

Let's take H as something like Manhattan distance, where 14 is a diagonal jump and 10 is a move to a direct neighbour. This is actually be the perfect heuristic for this example, as it's exactly the same as the actual distance. This will be different once there are obstacles in the path.

Then we get H values as:

```
    34
  24  30
14   R  34
  10  24
G   14
```

So our F values (= G + H) are:

```
    48
  34  40
28   R  48
  20  34
G   28
```

Then you find the minimum, which is 20, explore all it's (unexplored) neighbours and find the minimum, which will be the goal in this case.

Note that it's a easy mistake to stop as soon as one of the neighbours is the target, rather than the node we are currently exploring. An admissible heuristic doesn't guarantee that we'll find the optimal path to the target if we do this.

Comment: How do I recognize a diagonal jump?

Comment: @SanduCezar I'm not sure. How does your coordinate system work? I might get it if `(1,5)` was `(2,5)`, then it looks like 2 rows are at the same x-coordinate. It does seem a bit complicated to work with, at the very least the calculation is not going to be that straight-forward. As an easier option, just dividing your current H by 2 should do it (i.e. multiplying by 5 instead of 10), although this would be worse - it would take longer to get to the result.

Comment: Oh , sorry about that . It seems I made a mistake , sorry again for the confusion, yeah you're right it should've been (2,5) instead of (1,5).